# What can the additive group of a field look like?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

Is there a "nice" classification/characterization of the groups that can be additive groups of a field?

One interesting constraint is that $\phi_a:x\mapsto ax$ is an automorphism on $G$ for all nonzero $a\in G$.

Comment: For one thing, if the field has characteristic $p$ then every nonzero element has order $p$; if the field has characteristic 0 then the additive group is torsion-free.

Comment: I think that your second sentence makes little sense. What is $ax$ if we don't already know that the group is embedded in the additive group of at least a ring?

Comment: Every such group is a direct sum of some number of copies of an additive group of prime order or of $\mathbb Q$. Does that count as nice or...? I’m not sure what else you’d say beyond that.

Comment: @MatheinBoulomenos well it would imply that given any nonzero pair $a,b\in G$ there exists an automorphism mapping $a$ to $b$. So every nonzero element is "fungible" and this imposes a lot of symmetry on the group.